# What is the time complexity of the following code. my limitation is O(str.length())

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

my limitation to solve the problem is O(str.length()) for each test case, so I need to know what the time complexity for the following code:

```
File file = new File("input.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
            String Epass = sc.nextLine();
            HashMap<Character,Boolean> k=new HashMap<Character,Boolean>();
            String Rpass="";
            
            for(int j=0;j<Epass.length();j++){
                if(!(k.containsKey(Epass.charAt(j)))){
                    k.put(Epass.charAt(j),true);
                    Rpass+=Epass.charAt(j);
                 }
                
            }
            
            System.out.println(Rpass);
            
         }
```

sample input:

```
2
aaayyddjjkfff
abc
```

sample output:

```
aydjkf
abc
```

Comment: Your code has time complexity O(n) (or O(str.length)), because str.length is the sum of the characters per line, and you loop over each line, and then over each character in that line.

Comment: If we assume that all the operations on the HashMap need (in general) O(1) you only need to consider that `Rpass+=Epass.charAt(j);` is not O(1).